# Computing the expectation of $X^n e^{-\lambda X}$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, improper-integrals, expectation

Is there an elegant (probabilistic) way to compute $E(X^n e^{-\lambda X})$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lambda > 0$ and $X$ is a random variable with normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Alternatively, my question is simply how to compute the integral
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n e^{-\lambda x} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lambda x + \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} = \frac{x^2 - 2(\mu - \sigma^2 \lambda)x + \mu^2}{2\sigma^2} = \frac{(x-(\mu-\sigma^2 \lambda))^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{2 \lambda \mu -\sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2}$$

Ignoring constant factors, your integral becomes
$$\int x^n e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu-\sigma^2 \lambda))^2}{2\sigma^2}} \mathop{dx},$$
which can be computed from the [non-central] moments of a $N(\mu-\sigma^2 \lambda, \sigma^2)$ distribution.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
You have
$$
\begin{split}
\lambda x + \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}
&= \frac{x^2 + \mu^2 + 2x(\sigma^2\lambda-\mu)}{2\sigma^2} \\
&= \frac{x^2 + 2x(\sigma^2\lambda-\mu) +(\sigma^2\lambda-\mu)^2}
        {2\sigma^2}
  + \frac{\mu^2 - (\sigma^2\lambda-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\\
&= \frac{(x + \sigma^2\lambda-\mu)^2}
        {2\sigma^2}
  + \frac{\mu^2 - (\sigma^2\lambda-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\\
\end{split}
$$
and denote the last term on the RHS by $K$ and you have
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} x^n e^{\lambda x} e^{\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx
= e^K\int_\mathbb{R} x^n \exp\left(\frac{(x + (\sigma^2\lambda-\mu))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) dx
= e^K \mathbb{E}[Y]
$$
where $Y$ is also normal with same std deviation but shifted mean.

Answer (score 2):

The exponential generating function of the sequence $A_n = \mathbb E[X^n e^{-\lambda X}]$ is 
$$ g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A_n}{n!} z^n = \mathbb E[e^{(z-\lambda)X}]
= \exp\left(\frac{\sigma^2 (z-\lambda)^2}{2} + 2 \mu (z - \lambda) \right)$$
and $A_n$ can be obtained from the Maclaurin series of that.

Answer (score 0):

First, let
$$
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2},
$$
and recall that the moment generating function of the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is given by
$$
M_X(t) = E\left(e^{tX}\right) = \exp\left(\mu t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2\right).
$$ 
Second, notice that
$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} e^{-\lambda x} = -x e^{-\lambda x}, 
$$
and
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda^2} e^{-\lambda x} = x^2 e^{-\lambda x};
$$
accordingly, by mathematical indication, we get
$$
\dfrac{\partial^n}{\partial \lambda^n} e^{-\lambda x} = (-1)^n x^n e^{-\lambda x}.
$$
Hence, by using Leibniz integral rule, the given expected value can be rewritten as
$$
E\left(X^n e^{-\lambda X}\right) = (-1)^{-n} \int_\mathbb{R} \dfrac{\partial^n}{\partial \lambda^n} e^{-\lambda x} f(x) dx = (-1)^{-n} \dfrac{d^n}{d \lambda^n} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\lambda x} f(x) dx  = (-1)^{-n} \dfrac{d^n}{d \lambda^n} M_X(-\lambda) = (-1)^{-n} \dfrac{d^n}{d \lambda^n} \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \lambda^2 - \mu \lambda\right).
$$

Finally, depending on the value of $n$ and $\lambda$, you can determine the desired expectation. For instance, if $n = 1$, then 
$$
E\left(X e^{-\lambda X}\right) = \left(\mu - \lambda \sigma^2\right) M_X(-\lambda).
$$